# How to create a breakpoint programmatically on Android

Tags: java, android, debugging, breakpoints

In C# I can write:

```
if(Debugger.IsAttached)
    Debugger.Break();
```

This has no effect when the program is not being debugged. When a debugger is attached, it behaves like a breakpoint that can never be turned off. How can I achieve similar effect on Android?

Or maybe I should not focus on breakpoints at all. What I really want is to have no consequence in regular use (a generic error message will be shown to the user), but have the source of error become obvious the moment a dev will start looking at it. I've tried assert, but it's a sub-project that's compiled to release flavor most of the time and I can't rely on someone remembering to switch it to debug.

Comment: I have never heard that setting break points from within the debuggee on Java/Android is possible. Usually breakpoints a set by the debugger, not by the debugee.

Comment: @Robert The concept itself is quite old, we've got `__asm__("int $3");`, `DebugBreak();` and so on. I couldn't manage to find Java equivalent, just as you say.

Comment: In c# you actually don't need to bother yourself with `if(Debuuger.IsAttached)`. Just put `Debugger.Break()` and it will be stop execution for you when debugging and have absolutely no effect in Release build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that `Debug.isDebuggerConnected()` is what you are looking for. This will return `true` only if the app is started with debugger attached and `false` otherwise, no matter of `build type` or `flavor`. Unfortunately, I don't think that you can stop the execution programatically, but with the above instruction you should be able to display an error message or throw an exception. Personally, I'm thinking to something like this:

```
if (Debug.isDebuggerConnected()) {
    // throw an exception for the developer with a detailed message
} else {
    // show the general error message to the user with a dialog/toast    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also hoping that this could be done, but I've not found any reasonable way to programmatically cause the debugger to breakpoint.  What I've done to get around this problem is to create a breakpoint class with a method call "br".  When I'm debugging, I'll set a breakpoint in the "br" method.  After that, whenever my code calls the "br" method, the debugger stops.  I then step out of that method and then inspect the state of the program where the "br" method was called. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If i clear understand you - try this snippet of code:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        // Your, developers behavior
    }
    else {
        // release behavior
    }
```

Comment: I think he need a breakpoint, where the program could stop rather some code which will called in build.

Comment: The flavor is release so `BuildConfig.DEBUG` = false;

Comment: @Michel_T. In the worst case scenario I can throw some nasty exception - that should get some attention. But only if I could be 100% sure that somebody is actually watching.

Comment: did you try to add breakpoint with condition in you IDE? Do you use Android Studio or IDEa?

Comment: @Agent_L You could save debug info (e.g. callstack, values of variables etc.) to a logfile and watch it later. Not the best decision, of course.

Comment: @dosssik I don't want to set a breakpoint for me. I want to set a breakpoint that will tell what's wrong to the dev that will come 10 years later.

Comment: @Agent_L in that case, guess, better to throw an exception,,

Comment: @dosssik Impossible. A crash in production is not acceptable.

Comment: @Agent_L You can handle exception, and print error stacktrace in Log.e for exapmle. And, sure, don't crush production. This is not best solution, but something